# Magento 2 : pending registration activation email - reminder mail module/extension

Tags: magento2, extensions, email, register, email-reminders

Is there any free module or extension in magento 2 which allows to configure and send the email as a reminder email,if user have not activated their account by the user registration activation link sent in the earlier email.

Any existing reference modules from which i can implement above functionality,please do suggest that also.

Thanks in advance....